# filter a form using multiple combo boxes that build on each other

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox

I am using a form that displays all fields in my table in access 2016. I would like to create 5 combo boxes that build on each other each time I select my options from the drop down lists. Also, I want my filters to work right away (written on the after update section) - I don't want to click a button to work out my filters. The only button I'm interested in is a "clear all filters". I think all my combo boxes are strings; i name them: cboCaseType, cboReviewer, cboMonth, cboCompleted, cboClientName.
My table is huge and therefore I usually navigate with up to 5 filters on a daily basis on the back-end. It would be great if I could have it on the front-end form.

I chose my month field as a text instead of dates for convenience purposes. It displays it as 201710. could you please tell me how i could achieve it? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: This is called cascading or dependent comboboxes. Common topic. If you don't want a button, code would have to be in each combobox AfterUpdate event to set filter or to call a procedure that sets filter or use a dynamic parameterized query as form RecordSource and code would requery form. Now develop code and when you encounter specific issue, post question.

Comment: You month field stored as text will come back and bite you as a bad choice. Store dates as dates, and you can easily extract any parts of the date you want. Text can and will be mis input 210702 or 20172 ? which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will get some excellent code and a sample database here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

It does use a button to apply the filter, but you could adapt it easily to filter after each combo update.